# Ruby Initialize a Variable to Current Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, updates

I have a Rails 3 Application that needs to use the current time. Every time an admin uses a function `populateTable`, the `lastPopulation` variable needs to update to the current time. Two questions:

1) How can I initially set the `lastPopulation` variable to the current time right now?

2) Is there an assignment similar to `@lastUpdate = Time.now` for whenever the `populateTable` method is called?

All help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write after_filter to set the lastPopulation, Like

```
after_filter :set_last_polulated, :only => ['populateTable']

def set_last_polulated
@lastPolulation = DateTime.now
end
```

Comment: What exactly is `after_filter`?

Comment: This is filter which will be called after populateTable method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for [DateTime#current](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-c-current)

```
lastPopulation = DateTime.current
```